# Imagem não atualiza

Tags: java, swing

Estou fazendo uma aplicação aonde uso um JFileChooser para escolher uma imagem, pego essa imagem e copio ele para uma pasta que fica em rede. Depois disso ele executa um método que mostra essa imagem salva em uma Label, transformada em icon.

O problema mora aqui: Quando eu tento carregar uma imagem diferente e salvando com o mesmo nome ao exibir essa imagem, ela continua como se fosse a antiga. Somente mostra a nova quando eu fecho a aplicação e abro novamente.

**Lembrando que quero manter esse nome de IMG como "1.png"**

```
public void testesComChooser() {

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Somente Imagens", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

            chooser.setDialogTitle("Selecione uma foto");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            int resultado = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);

            if(resultado == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                salvarArquivo(file);
            }else {

            }

        }

        private void salvarArquivo(File img){

            String nomeImg = "1.png";
            String caminho = "C:\\imagens\\";

            Path pathDiretorio = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(caminho, nomeImg);

            try {
             //   Files.deleteIfExists(pathDiretorio);
                Files.copy(img.toPath(), pathDiretorio, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            visualizarImg(nomeImg);

        }

        private void visualizarImg(String nomeImg) {

            String caminho = "C:\\imagens\\";
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(caminho + nomeImg));
            label.setIcon(icon);
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** do seu código, para que seja possivel executar e testar o problema.

Comment: Disponibilizei os códigos, os metodos utilizados para fazer oq foi citado no inicio está nos códigos, esse é o exemplo!

Comment: Não é um exemplo completo e verificavel, como se trata de swing, você precisa fornecer um exemplo completo, esses metodos soltos não são executaveis. Recomendo que leia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/28595

Comment: Desculpe pelo erro. Espero que agora esteja correto.

Comment: Ainda não é um exemplo mínimo completo e executável. Por favor leia os links para ver como fazer isso.

Comment: Bom, sinceramente não estou entendo oq falta, sei que sou iniciante aqui, mas o código está completo. Realmente necessita de todo o código, não há como tirar mais nada. Deixei o código gerado pelo NetBeans somente para de ficar fácil de copiar.

Comment: Tirei todo o resto, deixei somente os metodos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está usando o método `Toolkit.getImage(String)` que, pela [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage-java.lang.String-), não necessáriamemte retorna o conteúdo atual do arquivo mas pode retornar uma imagem anteriormente carregada desse arquivo (usa um cache). A [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage-java.lang.String-) também sugere o que fazer: chamar o método `flush` da imagem retornada na chamada anterior:

> *If the image data contained in the specified file changes, the Image object returned from this method may still contain stale information which was loaded from the file after a prior call. Previously loaded image data can be manually discarded by calling the `flush` method on the returned Image.*

Aconselho a usar a classe `javax.imagio.ImageIO para ler imagens` - método [read(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) - é mais *moderna* e não tem esse problema do `Toolkit`.

Obs: o `Toolkit` não deve ser usado diretamente:

> *Most applications should not call any of the methods in this class directly.*

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo. Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Não sabia sobre esse cache, mas imaginei que seria algo do tipo.